# Using a variable to select a row from a html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to use this code to select a particular row

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
table.rows[0].cells[3].innerHTML = 'here';
```

and instead of entering the row number I want to put a variable holding a number inside so I can locate a specific row.
The number of rows on the table can change.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It may be that I got you wrong... but why don't you just use this variable of yours as the rows index:
table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML = 'here';

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. When I put a variable inside it would say 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/60hjtnr2/

Here's a working example.

Comment: Now it works, thanks. I think the problem was the variable that I was trying to use is global. So I guess that's a problem?

Answer (score -1):

```js
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
table.rows[0].cells[3].innerHTML = 'here';
```

```html
<table id="mytable" border="2">
<tr>
 <td>25</td>
 <td>25</td>
 <td>25</td>
 <td>25</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this isn't a solution for the problem... you only added the html part for the question...